Admin LTE 3 BootStrap Sidebar Navigation Not Dropping Down
So I'm building a dashboard with Laravel - Vue 3 and using Admin LTE 3 as a UI Template which is Bootstrap essentially. I am creating the sidebar however my nav-treeview a dropdown for a the sidebar is not working, any reasons why ? here is the code :
        <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="info">
                <a href="#" class="d-block">{{ authUserStore.user.name }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="mt-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/admin/dashboard" active-class="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                        <p>
                            Dashboard
                        </p>
                    </router-link>
                </li>

                <!-- Requests Dropdown -->
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="nav-icon fas fa-calculator"></i>
                    <p>
                        Kalkulator
                        <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                    </p>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a>
                            <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                            <p>Kalkulator KPR</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a>
                            <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                            <p>Kalkulator Cara Bayar</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                <!-- End Requests Dropdown -->

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/admin/appointments" active-class="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-envelope"></i>
                        <p>
                            Form Absensi
                        </p>
                    </router-link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/admin/cuti" active-class="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon far fa-envelope"></i>
                        <p>
                            Form Cuti
                        </p>
                    </router-link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/admin/approval" active-class="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-clipboard-check"></i>
                        <p>
                            Form Approval
                        </p>
                    </router-link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/admin/users" active-class="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-users"></i>
                        <p>
                            Users
                        </p>
                    </router-link>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/admin/settings" active-class="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-cog"></i>
                        <p>
                            Settings
                        </p>
                    </router-link>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/admin/profile" active-class="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-user"></i>
                        <p>
                            Profile
                        </p>
                    </router-link>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" @click="logout">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
                        <p>
                            Logout
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>

Everything else works however the nav-treeview doesn't, I have read the documentations and I think it might have to do with routing I assume but im not sure
I read the documents but honestly, it still doesn't work, quite lost maybe there is something within Laravel that is stopping it, because I have used this in a basic PHP - HTML web app and it works.

Can you please be more explicit as of "the sidebar is not working"? A [repro] is welcome.
